# Google Maps - Toggle on/off Polygon

Tags: google-maps, checkbox, toggle, polygon, event-listener

I have 50 polygons on my google map, 25 of which end in '_6' and the other 25 ending in '_100' I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of an example where check boxes are used to toggle polygons on and off based on a variable such as the name?

Below is an example of the current options I have for one of the polygons, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

```
var Zone_25_Distance_100 = new google.maps.Polygon({

paths: Zone_25_Distance_100,
strokeColor: '#48DD00',
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWeight: 1,
fillColor: '#48DD00',
fillOpacity: 0.01
});

google.maps.event.addListener(Zone_25_Distance_100, 'click', function() {
top.frames['GraphFrame'].location.href = 'Zone_25_100.html';

});
```

Comment: To hide a polygon set its "map" property to null; to show it set it back to the map.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you elaborate on this for me? How do I link a tick/check box to switch the polys on and off? Thanks Again.

Comment: Add more of your code for context if you need more information.  If you are using HTML check boxes, click listener functions for them run in the global context, so you will need to be able to access your polygons and your map variable from the global context.

Answer (score 2):

The method `setVisible(bool)` is what you are looking for. It hides or show a polygon on the map.

[Here is the doc related to polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon)

You would then only have to bind a `click` function to one of the checkboxes you have and call that method on the polygon you want hidden.

EDIT :

Supose your checkboxe's id is `cbId` and your polygon is `Zone_25_Distance_100`, it would look like this (using jQuery):

```
$('#cbId').click(function () {
    Zone_25_Distance_100.setVisible(this.checked);
});
```

Without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('cbId').onclick=function(){
    Zone_25_Distance_100.setVisible(this.checked);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have got the setVisible function working on a manual basis, so setting certain polys to true or false...could you point me in the direction of how to bind a click function to this, it would be VERY much appreciated!